# How to separate users dashboard and model in django

Tags: python, django

I want to create a system that has two type of user.
Normal users and coaches.

How can I separate users when they login in system.
I want to separate their dashboard after they logged in.

Should I create two model? one model for users and one model for coaches?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use Django's built-in Groups feature, create a Coach group and check in your views if a user is part of that group. Or you extend AbstractUser by adding a boolean field `is_coach` (and set AUTH_USER_MODEL settings to your new User model). 
Then you can check this flag in your views.

The more interesting question is if you want to store extra information (add extra functionality on the user level) for coach type users. If this is the case, you can make a so called Profile model `Coach` which you set in one-to-one relation with the User model (which should only serve authentication purposes). Then you can add extra fields in your profile model to store information relevant to coaches. The next question would be: what about students? Should students be able to enroll in courses?

Comment: thanks. extending AbstractUser is a good way. I’ll check in views and redirect users to their own panel by the flag situation. I also check the group built-in feature. and for registration I create two type of pages. one for users that in the view the flag is is_coach=False and one page for coaches registration that flag is True. and for their extra information as you said I will create Profile model. but what about normal users information should I create a Profile model for them as well?

Comment: Before adding a boolean field of `is_coach` you might want to think in the future if there will be more roles and dashboard or it will only be these two type of users.  If there will be more roles in the future personally I wouldn't suggest a boolean field but instead `enum` or something like that which would give you more flexibilities in the future